# Opacity in Mathematica 12.1 not working properly

Tags: linux, version-12.1, opacity

In Mathematica 12.1 if I try use `Opacity` less than 1, it does not work.

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1],Sphere[]}]

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]]
```

Even if I try to execute `Opacity`-related example from the documentation it does not work.
I am using Mathematica 12.1 in Linux by the way.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe provide some code of what you are trying to do, what you expect, an what you are seeing. Simply saying "it doesn't work", doesn't give anyone much to work off!

Comment: Sorry. Its actually opacity under Plot3D or Graphics3D not working. Say, Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]] this code , it returns a blank box , but changing opacity to 1 it shows the sphere

Comment: This looks like one of those times where a screenshot, as well as the code you are evaluating (in *copyable* form) should be supplied.

Comment: When I said **copyable** code, this is like the code from your comment that I added to your question. Next time, please do this yourself.

Comment: You should contact Wolfram with this.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Mathematica?

Comment: I am gonna install it again , if that doesn't work may be I will contact Wolfram.

Comment: Code works for me with Version 12.1

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem

Comment: Any updates on this? I am having the same issue now. Version 12.1.

Comment: Anyone knows if this was fixed on 12.3?

Answer (score 11):

I contacted Wolfram, and they told me another workaround that doesn't require using the -mesa option (which removes antialiasing and is slow since it renders on the CPU). You can use HardwareDepthPeeling like in:

```
Style[
  Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2},PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]],
  RenderingOptions -> {"3DRenderingMethod" -> "HardwareDepthPeeling"}
]
```

This can be enabled globally in the Options Inspector:

```
Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Open Option Inspector
Graphics Options -> RendreingOptions -> "3DRenderingMethod" -> "HardwareDepthPeeling"
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix the Opacity issue in Manjaro KDE (Kernel: 5.4.40-1) going to the Option Inspector to modify the settings for:

Graphics Options > RenderingOptions > "Graphics3DRenderingEngine"

to change from > "Automatic" to > "Mesa". The other option available: "OpenGL" doesn't work and I do not really know whether it should or what does it mean.
Also a font rendering issue for the labels in Plot3D was fixed in this way.

Additional comments related to this issue are more than welcome.

Comment: There's also the old solution of starting *Mathematica* as `mathematica -mesa` from e.g. the command line.

Comment: For me the `-mesa` solution did work as well but the rendering was quite underwhelming. If you have a dedicated Nvidia GPU like I do, you can make use of [bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee) (uses dGPU only on demand to save power). Just start the binary via command line with `primusrun mathematica &`.

Comment: This solution didn't actually work for me

Comment: To save someone some time: Option inspector is by default opened using Shift+Ctrl+O. You need to set "shop options value" to global if you want to fix this globally. It works for me Ubuntu 20.04. I am not sure whether it has a detrimental effect on rendering time and output.

Comment: @PandaScience, could you expand on your solution? I do not have primusrun installed by default and don't understand whether it would do me any good. I do have a Nvidia GPU, but don't know what bumblebee or primusrun is.

Comment: The solution above worked for me but brought about new problems with plotting especially in 3D. In the end I managed to solve this problem and the new once I encountered after switching by switching back to `OpenGL` AND changing my GPU drivers from the open source `nouveau` ones that come with Ubuntu to the proprietary `Nvidia` drivers. Now everything seems to work (for now). See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255306/45020

Answer (score 4):

Your code works fine on version 12.1 with my Mac, using OS Catalina 10.15.3:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.1], Sphere[]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8]]
```

[image: picture]

Comment: I am using Linux (Manjaro 20.0). Here the opacity is not working!

Comment: Sounds like you should inform Wolfram Research.

Comment: Or change the Linux distribution. This works all fine on Mathematica 12.1 on CentOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: @RolfMertig what Linux kernel version are you using ?

Comment: @puppe22: 2.6 and 5.0. I doubt it has anything to do with the kernel version. Maybe your you windows manager or your graphics card matters? XFCE or what do you use?

Comment: @RolfMertig Currently using KDE . I had the same problem in Gnome too . I guess the problem is with Arch

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the Arch Linux Mathematica package, and I actually get the correct output and no crash :/  This is weird, perhaps a missing dependency?

Comment: @JP-Ellis so i found if i run mathematica disabling GPU acceleration , then everything works fine .

Comment: @puppet22 If it's a GPU acceleration issue, then this might be reproducible on other Linux distributions?  And perhaps should be raised with Wolfram itself?

Comment: This is definitely not just an Arch Linux issue. I currently have this issue on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems with Opacity and you are using a Linux system with a Nvidia graphics card:

I had the same problem and initially followed the answer by Bob. However, while the `Mesa` engine did fix the Opacity issue it introduced other problems. In the end I managed to fix all problems by instead changing the drivers for my GPU from the open source `nouveau` ones that come with Ubuntu to the proprietary Nvidia ones. With the Nvidia drivers `OpenGL` correctly showed transparent surfaces and no new problems have arisen (yet).

To switch symply go to the `additional drivers` application and it should show you the available drivers for your Nvidia GPU.

---

See also this related answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/255306/45020