# How to create and export high quality 3D plots with straight axes

Tags: graphics3d, front-end, export, rendering, antialiasing

When I create a 3d plot (say with `ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]` the axes lines look quite bad. For example the z-direction axes, which due to the perspective are not exactly vertical in the 2D perspective, seem to be approximated in terms of many vertical lines. This looks quite terrible. Is there a way to improve this so that the axes lines really look straight. The issue is not in the method of export. It is already present within the `.nb` and happens both when exporting to `.png` and to `.pdf`.

---

"12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

[image: Example of low quality axes lines.]

Comment: Try an orthographic projection `ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, ViewPoint -> {5, 2, 3}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", BoxRatios -> 1]` If you don't want that, and just want to smooth the lines, then you need antialiasing on your plot. Enable this in your preferences.

Comment: @flinty, thanks. I turned `Preferences/Appearance/Graphics` antialiasing slider all the way to `Highest quality`. This perhaps helped a little bit but the problem is still there. Similarly ` ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"` can maybe mitigate some of  the problem by fixing the worst offender of the z-axis but the problem remains for the other axes.

Comment: This is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/4954079

Comment: This could be a limitation of your graphics processor, drivers, and screen resolution since you have maxed antialiasing and still have issues.  I see issues using a 4k screen.  What are you using and which version of Mma?

Comment: @yarchik, thanks. I tried applying `antialias` but applying it to a plot A it produces a smaller plot A'. If I resize plot A' to the same size as A it gives something a lot worse than A. Am I instead supposed to make a plot B that is say 3 times as big as A, and then apply `antialias[#,3]&` to it in order to make a plot of the same size as A. I tried this which might be giving an improvement for the axes but now I have to rescale all individual components since the ticks and label sizes are now much smaller. What is the correct procedure for using this function?

Comment: @Edmund, not using a 4k screen. Using Mathematica and had to change to the Mesa renderer following https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222365/45020. It seems that is the issue. It seems that on Ubuntu you simply cannot have both Opacity and antialiasing which is quite terrible.

Comment: I am not very familiar with this functions, however, 72 could be too small. Try 144 instead and apply it to the original plot. If it does not help, post a comment at that post. The author, @Szabolcs, should be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

The low quality plots where a consequence of using the `Mesa` rendering engine. I earlier had to switch to this because `Opacity` was not working correctly with `OpenGL` see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222365/45020. This fixed the opacity issue but apparently introduces this antialiasing problem.

I changed the drivers for my Nvidia Graphics card from the open source `nouveau` ones that come with Ubuntu to the proprietary Nvidia ones. Then I changed back the rendering engine to `OpenGL`. I then had to once more move the anti-aliasing slider found in `Preferences/Appearance/Graphics` all the way to `Highest quality`. It had moved back, I guess when switching the rendering engine (?). Using the Nvidia drivers it seems (for now) that both the Opacity and the anti-aliasing are working well, so this was indeed a GPU driver issue.

---

Thanks to flinty for pointing out the antialiasing slider and to Edmund for pointing out this was likely a graphics driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]], TicksStyle -> Black]
```

I hope it helps.